# How to make editable false kendo grid particular column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My requirement is want to make editable false one of the column in kendo grid. That column name(Primary Key Column) will get to know dynamically. 
   what i meant to say editable false want to add dynamically on that column.  Here the grid also i am generating dynamically.

Here the dojo example. Please make any one the column editable false. Anyone please help me to achive this.

Please look my dojo link .... http://dojo.telerik.com/UsEcO

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-make-a-non-editable-column-field

Comment: @erikscandola - Actually i tried it's not working. please check my dojo link where did wrong.

Answer (score 2):

How @erikscandola wrote, you can make not editable field through schema in dataSource.

```
fields: {
    Customer18Jan16_ObjNo: {editable: false}
}
```

After that field won't be editable but you will want hide label yet (probably). It can be done through jQuery.

```
e.container.find("label[for=Customer18Jan16_ObjNo]").hide();
```

in your grid_edit method.

Here [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/UsEcO/5)